# Calcular cuenta con selects javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, select

los datos seleccionados en los selects el value se guarda en el textarea pedido y la cuenta se tiene que guardar en el textarea cuenta.

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
                    <script>

                    function calcular(){
                    var cuenta=0.00:
                    
                    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val()+"\n"+$('#Pizzas option:selected').text());
var newPrice=cuenta;
                     var newPrice+=parseFloat($(this).find('#Pizzas option:selected').attr('precio'));
    
                    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val()+"\n"+$('#Bebidas option:selected').text());
var newPrice+=parseFloat($(this).find('#Bebidas option:selected').attr('precio'));
$("#cuenta").html(newPrice);
                }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Pizzas" name="Pizzas" class="form-control" >
<?php
<option value="<?php echo $datos[0];?>" precio="<?php echo $datos[1];?>"><?php echo $datos[0];?></option>

 <?php
           }
 ?>
 </select>
 
<select id="Bebidas" name="Bebidas" class="form-control" >
<?php
<option value="<?php echo $datos[0];?>" precio="<?php echo $datos[1];?>"><?php echo $datos[0];?></option>

     <?php
            }
     ?>
  </select>
<div class="col-12">
                            <div style="padding-left:20px;">
                            <textarea name="pedido" class="form-control" id="pedido" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Pedido" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                            </div>

<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                            <input type="text" name="cuenta" id="cuenta" class="form-control" placeholder="Cuenta" required  >
                        </div>
                            </div>
  <button name="añadir" type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3" onclick="calcular();"><span></span> Añadir al Pedido</button>
```

Los selects obtienen los datos de sql,tras seleccionar los datos y darle al botón añadir quiero que calcule la cuenta(sumando todos los precios de los seleccionados)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ví algunos errores de sintaxis y eso era lo que no dejaba lograr tu objetivo. Además, cambié algunas cosas de tu código que eran las causales del problema. Por ejemplo:

-No cerraste con `;` la variable *cuenta*

-Al momento de imprimir el valor en `#cuenta`, lo estabas haciendo con `.html()`, lo que es incorrecto porque estás tratando con un `input`, entonces lo correcto era cargar el valor con `.val()`

-Tambien al momento de concatenar los resultados con `cuenta`, tenías `+=` y es `=+`

-Estabas declarando varias veces la variable `newPrice`, lo cual generaba error de definición de variables

-Y por último, estabas accediendo incorrectamente al `option` del elemento `select`, pues el método `.find()` sólo accede a los hijos, y como tenías `$(this)` hacía referencia al botón, lo cual nunca te iba a encontrar el *select* y su respectiva *opción* porque los *select* no son elementos hijos del botón.

En conclusión, independicé las variables para obtener los respectivos valores del `select` y cambié la forma de acceder al elemento reemplazando `$(this)`, por `$('body')`, el cual es el elemento padre para que busque el `select`.

Espero haberme hecho explicar y haber podido aportar y ayudar con algo útil respecto a tu pregunta. !!!

```js
function calcular() {

  $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + "\n" + $('#Pizzas option:selected').text());
  var newPrice1 = parseFloat($('body').find('#Pizzas option:selected').attr('precio'));

  $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + "\n" + $('#Bebidas option:selected').text());
  var newPrice2 = parseFloat($('body').find('#Bebidas option:selected').attr('precio'));

  $("#cuenta").val(parseFloat($("#cuenta").val())+parseFloat(newPrice1) + parseFloat(newPrice2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Pizzas" name="Pizzas" class="form-control">
  <option value="1.1" precio="1.1">1.1</option>
  <option value="2.2" precio="2.2">2.2</option>
</select>

<select id="Bebidas" name="Bebidas" class="form-control">
  <option value="3.3" precio="3.3">3.3</option>
  <option value="4.4" precio="4.4">4.4</option>
</select>
<div class="col-12">
  <div style="padding-left:20px;">
    <textarea name="pedido" class="form-control" id="pedido" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Pedido"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
  <div style="padding-left:10px;">
    <input type="text" name="cuenta" id="cuenta" value="0" class="form-control" placeholder="Cuenta" required>
  </div>
</div>
<button name="añadir" type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3" onclick="calcular();"><span></span> Añadir al Pedido</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, falta que se actualice(anterior valor + el nuevo valor introducido) el valor de la cuenta tras pulsar varias veces el botón.

Comment: Que tras pulsar añadir pedido se vaya actualizando la cuenta con los valores de todo el pedido.

Comment: Edité la respuesta, para lograr lo que quieres, solo debes obtener el valor anterior del input `cuenta` y sumarlo al valor nuevo, es decir: `parseFloat($("#cuenta").val())`, y después viene el resto `parseFloat(newPrice1) + parseFloat(newPrice2)`... Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Y añadiendo un select de cantidad (1,2,3,4) .para cada select.¿como quedaría?

Comment: Se refiere a que los `option` sean enteros? Si es así, no inporta, la suma se hace normal, solo que sin los decimales

Comment: No,quiero otros select para elegir la cantidad de los productos , y calcular la cuenta en función de la cantidad

Comment: Ahhh... en ese caso, se deben crear variables que almacenen el valor de los nuevos `select` y obtener esos valores así como ya lo tienes, con `otion:selected`, y al final, sólo agrega a la suma `cuenta` esas variables.

Answer (score 0):

si no lo he entendido mal, quieres sumar los valores de ambos selects en el textArea `#pedido`, 
creo que esto solucionaría tu problema:

```
$('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + $('#Pizzas').val() + $('#Bebidas').val());
```

con *.val() en cualquier elemento Select recogerá el valor seleccionado en ese momento de forma automática.

Comment: no,quiero coger el valor de la etiqueta pedido de cada select para realizar la suma ,y esta llevarla al textarea cuenta

Comment: De la etiqueta precio*